# Reference for homotopy orbits of pointed spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, equivariant-homotopy, at.algebraic-topology

Can someone point me to a good (hopefully simple and brief) place to read about the basics
of homotopy orbits for pointed spaces?

More detail:
As I understand it, in the unpointed case, 
we use the projection $\mathrm{pr}_X: EG \times X \to X$
to replace the $G$-shaped diagram $X$ with the cofibrant $G$-shaped
diagram $EG\times X$;   and then the homotopy orbit space is the 
homotopy colimit of the diagram $X$, which is the categorical 
colimit of $EG\times X$.

I'd like a description of the pointed case in which it is shown that 
$EG_+ \wedge X\to X$ is a cofibrant replacement in the appropriate 
category of diagrams.

Even More (Inspired by T. Goodwillie's comment):
This is what I think, too, but I feel like I'm missing 
something, because in the pointed case, why can't I just use 
the cone on $G$ instead of $EG$?  It is contractible and $G$ acts 
freely on the nonbasepoint
cells, right?  So I could just as easily use $CG_+ \wedge X$. 
but this is clearly wrong!

EDIT:  Cone idea is wrong because of the cone point, so I feel pretty good about
my understanding of the theory.
I'd still like a good reference.

Comment: Hi Jeff, could you provide a definition to stimulate our memory juices? 

Comment: Of course the details depend on which model structure you use for $G$-spaces (or more generally diagrams of a given shape). If you use the one where equivalences and fibrations are defined objectwise, then any cell complex with $G$ acting freely on the set of (nonbasepoint) cells is cofibrant, and smashing a cell complex with $EG_+$ achieves this.

Comment: $G$ does not act freely on the non-basepoint cells of $CG_+$.  You've added another point.

Comment: @Scott:  Thanks -- I wasn't thinking clearly, clearly.
